# Verify Receive and Change Addresses

Tags: paper-wallet, change, coldcard

I run a coldcard with Electrum and Electrum-Personal-Server. As I understand it, we use hardware wallets because we don't trust our laptops.

However, I've only been able to verify the sending addresses on the coldcard's screen when I sign transactions, as well as verify my own personal receiving addresses using the addresses explorer function: https://blog.coinkite.com/address-explorer/

What remains is to verify my change addresses.

I'd like to do this manually on my laptop, using a virtual machine (I imagine it'd have to be pretty specialized malware to interfere with that).

Does anyone have some resources for manually deriving native segwit addresses from xpubs that they can point me to?

Thank you,

Comment: Upon further research, the coldcard has built in change-address fraud detection: https://blog.coinkite.com/troublesome-change/

Also when signing a PSBT, after looking at the send address on the coldcard, you can also scroll down further to see the change address. (Once again, if anyone knows of good resources, please point to me to instructions for manually deriving change addresses manually from xpubs).